# Present perfect or simple past, which one to use when a specific time is not mentioned?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect

2. Is there a specific time mentioned?

The Simple Past is used when the time is CLEAR:
They met on Sunday.
My birthday was last week.
John started his business after he graduated.
(We know exactly when.)

The Present Perfect is used when the time is NOT SPECIFIC:
They have met already.
I have celebrated my 20th birthday.
John has started his business.
(We don't know exactly when.)

I found the above info [here](http://www.really-learn-english.com/simple-past-or-present-perfect.html) and in some other books.

I concluded that there is a difference between using simple past and present perfect when the exact time is not specified, i.e. using simple past in this case is not considered correct form. The reason I concluded this way is that if they were interchangeably usable in the case of indefinite time in past, it should have been mentioned both tenses are usable. But there is not any such thing here.

Is this conclusion wrong, according to American English?

Comment: No  these are bad rules. Try to find a better resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of confusion around this, and a lot of half-true "rules" are taught.

The actual rule for the present perfect is fairly simple. The present perfect is a **present** tense, designating a **present** situation, so it cannot be used with a temporal expression which does not **include** the present, the moment at which the sentence is uttered.

Consequently:

> <sup>ok</sup>The directors have met *is acceptable, because there is no temporal modifier. This merely asserts that the consequences of the fact of their meeting (whatever those consequences are) are now in play.*
>
> <sup>ok</sup>The directors have met this week *is acceptable, because the temporal modifier* this week *designates a timespan which includes the present: it runs from the beginning of the current week right up to the moment of speaking.*
>
> <sup>∗</sup> The directors have met last week *is not acceptable, because the temporal expression* last week *designates a timespan which lies entirely in the past, ending with the beginning of the current week.*

Note, however, that an entirely past temporal expression may be included in a present perfect sentence if it is 'bracketed' with commas or dashes or parentheses; it is then understood as a 'supplement', not integrated into the sentence but added to the sentence as an afterthought.

> <sup>ok</sup>The directors have met—just last week, as a matter of fact.

---

ADDED:
DamkerngT points out that you conclude that use of simple past with an indefinite temporal expression is incorrect. This is **not** the case. The simple past can be used with no temporal or with indefinite temporals:

> <sup>ok</sup>The directors met.
>   <sup>ok</sup>The directors met sometime.
>   <sup>ok</sup>The directors met before lunch.
>   <sup>ok</sup>The directors met after that.

The only sort of temporal which cannot be used with the simple past is one which cannot be interpreted as lying entirely in the past, such as *now* or *currently* or *tomorrow*.

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, it's about an assumption (i.e. the "conclusion") that could make *"The directors met."* incorrect, and this question is a verification of this assumption.

Comment: I think I can add something to StoneyB's answer.
#1 => **I didn't eat anything today**
#2 => **I haven't eat anything today**

Although we have time-specification, they have different connotation.

Comment: Well, *Jane came today* and *Peter came tomorrow* are both valid sentences.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I'll buy "Peter was coming tomorrow", but ?Peter came tomorrow?

Comment: @StonyB Thank you:-) You're a perfect teacher! The first time I read your answer, before the added part being included, I fully understood we can use simple past with or without mentioning a specific time in past, it was informative enough to help me understand  the conclusion was wrong. BTW, would you please, kindly help me to improve my shallow information on Englisg grammar by suggesting a or some good source(s) whether online or printed?

Comment: @Sina *CGEL* (the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*) is my go-to reference, but that's huge (1800+ pages!) and complex--and expensive. I'm afraid I don't know anything more accessible: I rely on 65 years' reading and wrestle with very technical papers when I'm perplexed. Or I go to Chat and ask folks like snail plane and Araucaria.